# Spring boot application can not connect to postgres in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

When i try to connect my spring boot application to postgres i have an erro `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to postgres:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.` What is my mistake? Thanks!

docker-compose.yml
`

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5433/animals
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=s
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: animals
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: darsmeved
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'
    restart: always
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring application can't connect to postgred in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814258/spring-application-cant-connect-to-postgred-in-docker)

Comment: Why you ask the same question twice?

Comment: i fixed that. But now i have new error. I deleted last question